Finding quartile in Python given mean, std.dev
Given the mean and standard deviation of a normal distribution, how in Python can I determine the quartile of a given point?
E.g.:

mu = 0.7
sigma = 0.1

Which quartile is the value 0.75 in, with Python?
I'm after the quartile itself, not the quartile bounds - i.e. a function should take m, s, and val, and return quartile in the range 0 to 3.

You should first find the formulas (doable with google), then give a shot at implementing them, and give more specific error / problem you have, so we can help with your code. You should always give a working piece of code in your questions, see [MRE], [Tour].

Thanks, I teach this, I'm fine working it out from first principles - the part I'm missing is which libs are good for doing this with OTS.

it seems to me, this is  a quite simple formula, so you can do you own function to calculate this. no lib needed. Can you ? then you calculate Q1, Q2, Q3 and you see where the value falls.

I'm guessing you don't have a good answer either :)

i can show you code for it. no lib needed, and  what is "OTS" ?

"off the shelf"

You can define your own function to return the quartile order, being 0,1,2 or 3
def normal_quartile(mu, sigma, value):
    quartiles = []
    quartiles.append( mu- 0.675*sigma )
    quartiles.append( mu )
    quartiles.append( mu+ 0.675*sigma )

    for i, q in enumerate(quartiles):
        if value < q:
            return i
    return 3

print( normal_quartile(0.7, 0.1, 0.55) )
print( normal_quartile(0.7, 0.1, 0.65) )
print( normal_quartile(0.7, 0.1, 0.75) )
print( normal_quartile(0.7, 0.1, 0.95) )

results are:
0
1
2
3


thanks! i should've just gone straight to the z-tables :)
